# Requiring a store in another store doesn't work

Tags: javascript, reactjs, flux, reactjs-flux

I am trying to use `Dispatcher.waitFor` but when I require one store in another, it doesn't work.

So, when I dispatch `INIT` event, `StoreA` is handling it properly, but `StoreB` is not even showing debugging messages.

### StoreA.js

```
var Constants = require('../constants/Constants')
var Dispatcher = require('../dispatcher/Dispatcher')

StoreA.dispatchToken = Dispatcher.register(function (action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case ActionTypes.INIT:
      // ...
      // ...
      // ...
      StoreA.emitChange()
      break
  }
}
```

### StoreB.js

```
var ActionTypes = require('../constants/Constants').ActionTypes
var Dispatcher = require('../dispatcher/Dispatcher')
var StoreA = require('./StoreA')

StoreB.dispatchToken = Dispatcher.register(function (action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case ActionTypes.INIT:
      console.log('Wait for SectionStore')
      Dispatcher.waitFor([StoreA.dispatchToken])
      console.log('SectionStore Updated')
      // ...
      // ...
      // ...
      StoreB.emitChange()
      break
  }
}
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: The code you've posted looks fine. The problem is likely to be in the code you haven't posted, such as the exports, declarations of the store objects, components that are registered with StoreA, etc. For example, if the code that reacts to StoreA's change throws an exception, that would stop StoreB's handler from running. Have you debugged with the debugger set to stop on exceptions?

Answer (score 0):

Just from first glance, it looks like StoreA is missing:

```
var ActionTypes = require('../constants/Constants').ActionTypes
```

Additionally, are you seeing any error logs in the Developer Console?